# ApplyUpdates on REST with Firedac

Tags: json, rest, delphi, datasnap, firedac

My project uses a REST server with FireDac.

I have a generic function that makes all my Selects but when I try to ApplyUpdates if does nothings. No message, no crash, it just keeps going and the data is not reflected to the database.

My Code:

```
function TServerMethods.ApplyUpdates(banco, tabela : String; const DeltaList: TFDJSONDeltas; var Mensagem : String) : Boolean; 
var 
  LApply : IFDJSONDeltasApplyUpdates; 
  Query : TFDQuery; 
begin 
  mensagem := ''; 
  result := false; 
  try 
    try 
      LApply := TFDJSONDeltasApplyUpdates.Create(DeltaList); 
      Query := CriaQuery(banco,Tabela); 
      Query.Open(); 
      LApply.ApplyUpdates(banco + '.' + tabela, Query.Command); 
      if LApply.Errors.Count > 0 then 
        raise Exception.Create(LApply.Errors.Strings.ToString); 
      result := true; 
    except 
      on E:Exception do 
      begin 
        mensagem := 'Ocorreu um Erro na atualização: ' + #13#10 + E.Message; 
      end; 
    end; 
  finally 

  end; 

end;
```

The GetDeltas function (the function that generates the DeltaList):

```
function GetDeltas(Banco, Tabela : String; MemTable : TFDMemTable) : TFDJSONDeltas;
begin
  if MemTable.State in [dsInsert, dsEdit] then
    MemTable.Post;
  result := TFDJSONDeltas.Create;
  TFDJSONDeltasWriter.ListAdd(result, MemTable);
end;
```

My "CriaQuery" Function:

```
function TServerMethods.CriaQuery(Database : String; Tabela : String = '') : TFDQuery;
var
  FieldName : Boolean;
  i : Integer;
begin
  result := TFDQuery.Create(self);
  result.Connection := Connection;
  result.FetchOptions.AutoFetchAll := afAll;
  result.name := 'Qry' + Database + tabela;
  result.SQL.Clear;
  FieldName := false;
  if Trim(Tabela) <> '' then
  begin
    result.SQL := MontaSQL(database + '.' + tabela);
    result.SQL.Add(' and 1 = 0');
    result.Open();
    QryCampos.First;
    result.IndexFieldNames := result.Fields[1].FieldName;
    for i := 0 to result.Fields.Count-1 do
    begin
      if (UPPERCASE(Copy(result.Fields[i].FieldName, Length(result.Fields[i].FieldName)-1,2)) = 'ID') and
         (not FieldName) then
      begin
        result.Fields[i].ProviderFlags := [pfInUpdate, pfInWhere, pfInKey];
        FieldName := true;
      end
      else
        result.Fields[i].ProviderFlags := [pfInUpdate];
    end;
    result.Close;
    result.SQL.Delete(result.SQL.Count-1);
  end;
end;
```

Function that generates the bindings of the components:

```
procedure LinkaComponente(Campo : TField; Dono : TFmxObject; Classe : String);
var
  BindSource : TBindSourceDB;
  BindingList : TBindingsList;
  Link : TLinkControlToField;
begin
  if Dono is TForm then
  begin
    BindSource := TBindSourceDB.Create(Dono);
  end
  else
  begin
    BindSource := TBindSourceDB.Create(Dono.Owner);
  end;
  BindingList := TBindingsList.Create(BindSource.Owner);
  Link := TLinkControlToField.Create(BindSource.Owner);
  BindSource.DataSet := Campo.DataSet;

  if Classe = 'TCheckBox' then
  begin
    Link.Control := Dono.FindComponent(Campo.FieldName);
    Link.CustomFormat := 'ToStr(%s) <> "N"';
    Link.CustomParse  := 'IfThen(%s,"S","N")';
  end
  else if Classe = 'TFrameF2' then
  begin
    Link.Control := (Dono.FindComponent('Frame' + Campo.FieldName) as TFrameF2).edtFK;
  end
  else
    Link.Control := Dono.FindComponent(Campo.FieldName);
  Link.DataSource := BindSource;
  Link.FieldName := Campo.FieldName;
  Link.Active := true;
end;
```

the moment I call the applyUpdates function:

```
procedure TDMPadrao.DMApplyUpdates;
var
  Deltas : TFDJSONDeltas;
  Mensagem : String;
begin
  //repetir esses comando para todas as MemTables do DM na sua ordem de dependencia
  //       tabelas pai antes de tabelas filhas...
  try
    Deltas := GetDeltas(banco, tabela, FDMemTable);
  except
    on E:Exception do
    begin
      FDMemTable.Edit;
      MostraMensagemBasica('Ocorreu um Erro na atualização:' + #13#10 + E.Message);
      abort;
    end;
  end;
  if not DMClient.ServerMethodsClient.ApplyUpdates(banco, tabela, Deltas, Mensagem) then
  begin
    FDMemTable.Edit;
    MostraMensagemBasica(Mensagem);
    abort;
  end;
end;
```

Everything works fine when I'm reading. I Only get a problem when I call the ApplyUpdates function

Thanks.

Comment: This feature is known to work as expected. Must be something with your environment or code.

Comment: yeah I think my GetDeltar function or the function that creates my query has a problem.

Comment: Just a sugestion, use verbs in your method names, like "CriarQuery".

Comment: Cesar do you mind sending me your CreateQuery method?

Comment: @RicardoAlvaresPereiraJunior it creates a instance of TFDQuery and link the Connection and set the SQL statement. The default auto generated SQL is 'SELECT * FROM TableName', no other property is changed.

Comment: Gonna make a new project and try doing it from scratch to see if I can find the problem.

thanks.

Comment: Just noticed that from your client you call:
RestClientModule.CustomersMethodsClient.ApplyUpdates(Deltas);
and the method in the server is called: ApplyDeltas, what does the ApplyUpdate method do? just cal the applyDeltas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar problem and I got it resolved passing the table name to Query.UpdateOptions.UpdateTableName before ApplyUpdates.

- Are you doing it inside "CriaQuery"?
- What is your Delphi Version?

Here is my working code, I have tested it in Delphi XE7 e XE7 Update 1:

```
procedure TDBDM.ApplyDeltas(const ADeltaList: TFDJSONDeltas; const TableName: string);
var
  JSONDeltas: IFDJSONDeltasApplyUpdates;
  Query: TFDQuery;
begin
  JSONDeltas := TFDJSONDeltasApplyUpdates.Create(ADeltaList);
  Query := CreateQuery(TableName);
  try
    Query.UpdateOptions.UpdateTableName := TableName;
    JSONDeltas.ApplyUpdates(0, Query.Command);

    if JSONDeltas.Errors.Count > 0 then
    begin
      raise Exception.Create(JSONDeltas.Errors.Strings.Text);
    end;
  finally
    Query.Free;
  end;
end;
```

**Notes**

- different from your code, Query.Open is not called.
- **TFDMemTable.CachedUpdates** must be **True**

**Edit: Added the client side code to applyUpdates**

I call this method in TFDMemTable.AfterPost event.

```
    const
      CustomerTableName = 'CUSTOMER';

    procedure TCustomersDataModuleClient.ApplyUpdates;
    var
      Deltas: TFDJSONDeltas;
    begin
      Deltas := TFDJSONDeltas.Create;
      TFDJSONDeltasWriter.ListAdd(Deltas, CustomerTableName, CustomersMemTable);
      RestClientModule.CustomersMethodsClient.ApplyUpdates(Deltas);
      CustomersMemTable.CommitUpdates;
    end;
```

Comment: I got to something like urs today but it still isnt updating the database, the query.open line was added and removed lots of times to test.

Comment: I just copied you code without changing anything and it didn't update, would you mind giving me the code that generates your ADeltaList?

Comment: Oh, I use XE7. the problem is inside GetDeltas or CriaQuery I believe

Comment: Got it:
CachedUpdates was set to false in my FDMemTable

Comment: Man, I forgot about that. It will not works if CachedUpdates is false. Maybe I should add it to my answer, so people can use the information.